# Concatenate Strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Have edited the code, the updated code is below, This code is not able to fetch the keywords meta tag, hence it is not working.

**old description:** *I am trying to concatinate the strings to get the finalUrl, but I am not able to do so becuase of the tags variable. I need to fetch the keywords meta tag of the page and append it to get the finalUrl. Any help?*

```
  <script type="text/javascript">


    var tags=$('meta[name=keywords]').attr("content");
    var gameurl = "http://xyz/abc/details/";
    var jsn = ".json?callback=showGameDetail";
    var finalUrl= gameurl.concat(tags).concat(jsn);


function loadJSON(url) {
  var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
  var newScript = document.createElement('script');
      newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
      newScript.src = url;
  headID.appendChild(newScript);
}

function showGameDetail(feed){
  var title = feed.title;



    var game_url = feed.pscomurl;
    var packart_url = feed.Packart;
  $("#bnr-ads-box").html("<img src='"+"http://abc.com/"+packart_url+"'>");




}

loadJSON(finalUrl);
</script>
<div id="bnr-ads-box"></div>
```

Comment: Use a [plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/String_Operators): `var finalUrl = gameurl + tags + jsn;` - It is very googlable using string concatenation to get to MDN

Comment: If you are trying to evaluate the output of the jquery script you should not put it inside quote. Directly right `var tags=$('meta[name=keywords]').attr("content");`

Comment: I am sure you are missing tags var value here. Always debug whether you are getting right value if you gonna use it later

Comment: What is the out put of `tags` if you print it in console. `console.debug(tags)`. Post the output data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta id="metaK" name="keywords" content="customizable software for QuickBooks, QuickBooks-integrated, Method customization, CRM accounting, Method for QuickBooks, Method CRM, Method blog,  Salesforce automation, Method online platform, QuickBooks customization, web-based platform, industry-specific, customer portal, Method Field Services, Method Manufacturing, ERP" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>

<p id="demo">Click the button to join two strings into one new string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var tags=$('meta[name=keywords]').attr("content");

var gameurl = "http://xyz/abc/names/";
var jsn = ".json?callback=showGameDetail";
var finalUrl= gameurl.concat(tags).concat(jsn);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=finalUrl;
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't work when **var tags= $('meta[name=keywords]').attr("content");** 

Works if the value of tags is simple, lets say var tags = "name_of_page"

Comment: In my string "tags", let say I am getting following output
Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3, keyword4 but i need to use on Keyword1 to use in my finalUrl to make the URL, how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

change this

`var tags="$('meta[name=keywords]').attr("content");";`

to

```
var tags=$('meta[name=keywords]').attr("content");
```

also use this code `var finalUrl = gameurl + tags + jsn;`

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to escape the double quotes inside your tags variable, like so:

```
var tags="$('meta[name=keywords]').attr(\"content\");";
```

Cris' solution is also fine, but in some case you will need to have two sets of double quotes inside a string so you will be forced to do escaping correctly.

**FYI:** Escaping is the process  of having special characters getting generated in a string which would otherwise cause issues, for instance in javascript you can't have newlines in a string, like this:

```
var mystring = 'on
a different line'; // <- this causes a syntax error
```

So one would do the following:

```
var mystring = 'on\na different line';
```

Comment: See my answer which is using encodeURIComponent to avoid that

Comment: Actually, @mplungjan covered more stuff than mine - but it lacks some explaining. :)

Comment: Updated while you commented :)

Answer (score 1):

Tough debatable, you can use an array, which can be concatenated by calling `join()`:

```
var tags = $('meta[name=keywords]').attr("content");
var data = [
 "http://xyz/abc/names/",
 encodeURIComponent(tags),
 ".json?callback=showGameDetail"
].join('');
$("#demo").html(data);
```

Comment: Euuw. At least push the strings if you want to use an array

Comment: This is a very elegant solution than having all the stuff on one line. A different and elegant way would be to have the different strings in properly named variables: `var url = "http://xyz/abc/names/", query = ".json?callback=showGameDetail"; var data = url + encodeURIComponent(tags) + query;`

Comment: I do not see the elegance over having + in this particular example - it adds unnecessary [].join("")

Comment: No need to use push() as an array can be initialized directly. Besides it would be overkill to use push() if the main goal is to produce a string.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include the jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="keywords" content="hello"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
alert("Hello World!");
var tags=$('meta[name=keywords]').attr("content");

var gameurl = "http://xyz/abc/names/";
var jsn = ".json?callback=showGameDetail";
var finalUrl= gameurl.concat(tags).concat(jsn);
alert(finalUrl);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the concat method works on strings too (in chrome at least) but the recommended method is using  the [plus concatenation string operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/String_Operators)

You are however missing some stuff

1. jQuery library - I assume you want that since you have $(...) in the example
2. encoding of the string from the keywords - I use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to handle possible newlines and quotes in the keywords

.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Create a URL from keywords</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="These are tags" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var tags = $('meta[name=keywords]').attr("content");
      var URL ="http://xyz/abc/names/" +
       encodeURIComponent(tags) + 
       ".json?callback=showGameDetail";
      window.console &&  console.log(URL);
      $("#demo").html(URL);     
   }
   </script>
  <body>
    <p id="demo">Click the button to join two strings into one new string.</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question was misusing (actually, missing) the concept of string-escaping. I would cover this as well in my answer (as I already did) - at least for the sake of learning.

Comment: Is someone on a downvoting spree here? Why is this downvoted without comment?